# how to extract wsse BinarySecurityToken using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, plsql

How can I extract the BinarySecurityToken from the following SOAP payload using PL/SQL ?

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">expectedToken</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

I expect to extract "**expectedToken**" as result

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't neex PL/SQL; you can use an XQuery in plain SQL:

```
select XMLQuery('declare namespace wsse = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"; (::)
    /wsse:Security/wsse:BinarySecurityToken/text()'
  passing XMLType('<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">expectedToken</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>')
  returning content)
from dual;

XMLQUERY('DECLARENAMESPACEWSSE="HTTP://SCHEMAS.XMLSOAP.ORG/WS/2002/12/SECEXT";(:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
expectedToken
```

If you're already getting the response in PL/SQL and want to continue using it, then if the SOAP value is in a string variable you could do:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  soap varchar2(500);
  token varchar2(200);
begin
  soap := '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">expectedToken</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
</wsse:Security>';

  select XMLQuery('declare namespace wsse = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext"; (::)
    /wsse:Security/wsse:BinarySecurityToken/text()'
  passing XMLType(soap)
  returning content).getStringVal()
  into token
  from dual;

   dbms_output.put_line(token);
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

expectedToken
```

Comment: Hey Alex, Thank you very much indeed ! Regards